# How can I join these two html tables together?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to create a compare sort of page. I currently have two tables with the information, but want it to be on table or join both together. The first row would show Name of brand, second would show cost, etc... I am grabbing the values of selected checkboxs and based on what they selected it get compared.

```
$testName = $_POST['testCompare'];
$rpl = str_replace("_", " ", $testName);
$firstOne = "$rpl[0]";
$secondOne = "$rpl[1]";
echo "$firstOne";
echo "<br/>";
echo "$secondOne";

$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test_name = '$firstOne'";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test_name = '$secondOne'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die ("Error in query: $query2. " . mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 && mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {

//if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {            
        if ($firstOne == $row[1]) {
        {
            echo "<table border=1>";            
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        }echo "</table>";

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)) {          
        if ($secondOne == $row2[1]) {
        {   echo "<table border=1>";        
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row2[0] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row2[1] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row2[2] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row2[3] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row2[4] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
 else {
        echo "No Results";
    }[/CODE]
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly show the scheme of your database table? Also, before someone else is an ass about it, you have a SQL injection vulnerability as you're not escaping user input, i.e. passing the `$_POST` variable through without sanitizing it.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your code is incredibly insecure. Not only do you do no sanitization of your input, you don't use placeholders in your queries.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the `</table>` after the first loop.
2. Remove `<table border=1>` from **both loops**.
3. Add `<table border=1` before the first loop.

Currently, you're defining a new `<table border=1>` each time you enter the loop. This will result in this HTML code:

```
<table ..>
<tr>...
<table ..>
..
<table> 
..
Et cetera
</table>
<table ..>
Et cetera
</table>
```

Comment: If you want to have the two tables next to each other (horizontally), move `$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2)` from the second loop to the first loop, and add a `<td>` for each element, so that the HTML looks like `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>`. **Both results should have the equal number of elements**, if you want to use this method.